# Cross compiling rust project on armv7 using docker

Tags: rust, openssl, cross-compiling, armv7

I am trying to build my project for armv7 on a Mac (M1). The project uses openssl and declares it as dependency like this:

```
openssl = { version = "0.10", features = ["vendored"] }
```

I created a dockerfile like this

```
FROM rust:latest

RUN apt update && apt upgrade -y
RUN apt install -y g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf libc6-dev-armhf-cross openssl libssl-dev pkg-config

RUN rustup target add armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
RUN rustup toolchain install stable-armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf

WORKDIR /app

ENV CARGO_TARGET_ARMV7_UNKNOWN_LINUX_GNUEABIHF_LINKER=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc CC_armv7_unknown_Linux_gnueabihf=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc CXX_armv7_unknown_linux_gnueabihf=arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
RUN export OPENSSL_DIR=`openssl version -d`
CMD ["cargo", "build", "--target", "armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf", "--release"]
```

but when I lauch the image to build the project the build fails when compiling openssl. The error I get is this:

```
  --- stderr
  arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar: creating apps/libapps.a
  arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar: creating libssl.a
  arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar: creating libcrypto.a
  arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar: crypto/dso/dso_win32.o: Operation not permitted
  make[1]: *** [Makefile:727: libcrypto.a] Error 1
  make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  make: *** [Makefile:177: build_libs] Error 2
  thread 'main' panicked at '


  Error building OpenSSL:
      Command: cd "/app/target/armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/release/build/openssl-sys-5ca185d59ecdacfe/out/openssl-build/build/src" && MAKEFLAGS="-j --jobserver-fds=8,12 --jobserver-auth=8,12" "make" "build_libs"
      Exit status: exit status: 2


      ', /usr/local/cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/openssl-src-111.24.0+1.1.1s/src/lib.rs:498:13
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

I don't understand what is going on here.

Update: I tried with `cross` and the error is very similar:

```
  --- stderr
  <jemalloc>: MADV_DONTNEED does not work (memset will be used instead)
  <jemalloc>: (This is the expected behaviour if you are running under QEMU)
  make: Warning: File 'Makefile' has modification time 0.14 s in the future
  make: warning:  Clock skew detected.  Your build may be incomplete.
  crypto/asn1/a_int.c: In function 'asn1_string_get_int64':
  crypto/asn1/a_int.c:260:19: warning: 'r' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
           } else if (r == ABS_INT64_MIN) {
                     ^
  crypto/asn1/a_int.c:252:14: note: 'r' was declared here
       uint64_t r;
                ^
  arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar: creating apps/libapps.a
  arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar: creating libssl.a
  arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar: creating libcrypto.a
  arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar: crypto/des/pcbc_enc.o: Operation not permitted
  make[1]: *** [libcrypto.a] Error 1
  make: *** [build_libs] Error 2
  thread 'main' panicked at '


  Error building OpenSSL:
      Command: cd "/target/armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/debug/build/openssl-sys-e7e5ee7368f76501/out/openssl-build/build/src" && MAKEFLAGS="-j --jobserver-fds=15,16 --jobserver-auth=15,16" "make" "build_libs"
      Exit status: exit status: 2


      ', /cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/openssl-src-111.24.0+1.1.1s/src/lib.rs:498:13
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```